# ASP.NET => Spring Web Flow: How do I get up to speed fast?

Tags: spring, jsp, jsf, servlets, spring-webflow

I'm a long-time web developer who's been focusing on ASP.NET/C# for the past 5 years.  For my final Masters in Software Engineering project, my team is working with a local company to build them an app using Spring Web Flow (as that's their current tech stack).

I don't know the first thing about building web sites with Java.  In fact the last Java dev I did was in the mid-90's when I wrote a calculator applet (back when everyone thought applets would take over the world :-).  I know there are things called Servlets, and servlet containers, but I've lived in blissful ignorance about them until now.  On the other hand I consider myself a web application expert (not just from ASP.NET, but from classic ASP and Perl before that) and have some experience with the ASP.NET MVC framework as well as Ruby on Rails so I expect to see some similarities with the MVC implementation.  But after looking at the myriad xml configuration files last night I had to dig up my old baby blankie and suck my thumb for a bit.

So, Java masters... how would you go about getting a competent developer from a different tech background up to speed on the world of Java web development?  What sites have the best tutorials?  What books can help?  Keep in mind that I have one month before we start our first code sprint, but there should be time for me to do some good late night reading.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above that the fundamentals of servlets/jsp are first, followed by spring mvc.  On the topic of Spring webflow itself, you need to realise that this is quite different from most other mvc-type frameworks, and I'm not aware of a similar one in the .net world.  It makes some things really really easy, and other things really awkward.  The best ways to learn it are:

1) read the reference documentation
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html

2) look through the code in the samples
https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-webflow/spring-webflow-samples

3) beg, borrow or steal (or even buy) a copy of Spring in Action and read its webflow chapter.

4) Obviously, read blogs from people who tried out swf and do your own hello-world type projects to get the hang of it.

The main think with swf is to think of a framework that enables "wizards" which can guide you through a process, in that way it's more similar to a BPL than a web framework.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [SpringMVC step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) as a single tutorial.

Or if you prefer reference manuals:

1. General intro to dependency injection: spring reference documentation sections [3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-introduction), [3.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-basics) and [3.3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-dependencies), this should cover basic stuff so that you have some idea what those XMLs are all about.
2. Skim [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html) for a basic overview of the MVC concept used.
3. Skim [Spring web flow documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html) to get a feel what web flow is used for

Finally, of course:

1. Get someone from the local company to give you an introduction on the architecture of their specific application, so you get an understanding of what is being done in your specific case.
2. Google class names found in your XMLs to get a better understanding what functionality these classes provide.